# Create org-clock tasks from org subtree

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a list of tasks in the following form in an org-file

```
* Tasks
** task 1
** task 2
```

and would like to create subtasks under `* Tasks` that I can easily clock it to (eg. `task 1`, `task 2` etc popup when calling <kbd>C-u</kbd>`org-clock-in`. I was considering using `org-clock-history-push` in order to build the list of tasks but hadn't come accross a simple way to walk the org-mode header tree to create the tasks?  I was looking at [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17622/how-can-i-walk-an-org-mode-tree) link, but was hoping there was an alternative/org API that would accomplish this.

I would also be interested in a way to save clock history across `destop-sessions` without loading `org-mode` as my attempts at adding `org-clock-marker` and `org-clock-history` to `desktop-globals-to-save` haven't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own with inspiration from the linked post. This is code that will create and add tasks that aren't "DONE" to `org-clock-history` so they are readily acccessible via <kbd>C-u</kbd> `org-clock-in`.

```
(defun my-org-header-list (&optional header-re level buffer items)
  "Get the headers of an org buffer (default current buffer). Optionally,
narrows to headers matching HEADER-RE under nesting LEVEL (defaults all
headers). Returns plist list of headers with specified values in ITEMS when defined.
Defaults to header text, location, level, todo status. 
See `org-element-all-elements' for possible item types."
  (setq level (or level 0)) ;default all headers
  (save-restriction
    (with-current-buffer (or buffer (current-buffer))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (and header-re
           (re-search-forward header-re nil nil 1)
           (org-narrow-to-element))
      (let ((tree (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline)))
        (list :buffer (current-buffer)
              :headers
              (org-element-map tree 'headline
                (lambda (el)
                  (when (< level (org-element-property :level el))
                    (or (and items
                             (cl-loop for sym in items
                                nconc (list sym (org-element-property sym el))))
                        (list :raw-value (org-element-property :raw-value el) ;text
                              :begin (org-element-property :begin el) ;start
                              :end (org-element-property :end el)     ;end
                              :level (org-element-property :level el) ;depth
                              :todo-keyword (org-element-property :todo-keyword el))
                        )))))))))


;; construct list of tasks to choose from in clock history buffer
;; #<marker at 19296 in org-clock.el>
(defun my-org-clock-create (headers)
  "Create clock tasks for headers."
  (let ((buf (plist-get headers :buffer)))
    (cl-loop for h in (plist-get headers :headers)
       when (not (string= "DONE" (plist-get h :todo-keyword)))
       do (org-clock-history-push (plist-get h :begin) buf))))

;; generate a list of TODO tasks nested under Tasks heading from 
;; BUFFER-NAME
;;;###autoload
(defun my-org-clock-in (arg &optional buffer-name)
  (interactive "P")
  (my-org-clock-create
   (my-org-header-list
    (if arg (read-string "Task group: ") "Tasks") 1 (or buffer-name "gtd.org")
        '(:raw-value :begin :todo-keyword))))
```